# Adding properties in dynamic textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Userforms, Form1 and Form2. In Form1,the user will input how many dynamic textbox they need in Form2. The user input in the dynamic textboxes should be exactly 2 characters, not less than nor greater than.

My question is

1. How can I create a prompt that will show that the user input is less than 2? I managed to put the max limit property but it still accepts if the input value is only 1 character.
2. How can I create a prompt checking that the last letter of the input in Form1 to be the same as the first letter of the input in the dynamic textbox?

Sample Illustration:

```
Form1 User Input: BA               Form2 Dynamic Textbox: AD
                                                          AE
                                                          AF
                                                          AG
```

3. How can I capitalized the letters automatically entered in the dynamic textbox? I tried Ucase but didn't worked.

Here's my script for the dynamic textbox.

```
Private Sub Form2_Initialize()

textbox_count = Form1.txtbox_count.Value

Dim txtB1 As Control

For i = 1 To textbox_count
    Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    
    With txtB1
    .Name = "txtBox" & i
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 90
    .Left = 80
    .Top = 25 * i * 1
    End With
    
txtB1.MaxLength = 2
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Use textbox_change event and change backcolor to yellow for example if len(textbox.text)<2, and back to original color if len() = 2.

Comment: 2. A messagebox can be used, or an informational warning on a label control on the form that is populated by textbox_change on dynamic form, again checking for the letter and automatically deleting it if not same as form1.

Comment: 3.See answer as comment didn't look very nice.

Answer (score 1):

For number 3:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim bDisableUpdate As Boolean

    If Not bDisableUpdate Then
        bDisableUpdate = True
        TextBox1.Text = UCase(TextBox1.Text)
        bDisableUpdate = False
    End If
    
End Sub
```